# How to secure network manager with password?

Tags: dsl

In Ubuntu 12.04, how to Lock the Edit in DSL in Network connection. so that nobody can see my internet connection password (Isp password) Or network manager should ask for password everytime when I want to connect to internet.

Answer (score 0):

Create the connection as an administrative user -- check the "Available to All Users" check box. Then have users login as non-admin users.

[image]